# Should I compress email-attachments in a mysql-database with compress?

Tags: mysql, compression, email-attachments

I'm storing emails in a mysql-database and was wondering if it's a good idea to use compress (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_compress) to store the fetched email-attachments in the database to reduce the size of the database.

Why I'm hesitating is, that most attachments are already compressed (like jpg). The other reason is that I couldn't find anything about the efficence of the build-in compression-algo of MySql.

Comment: What are you expecting to be able to do with emails? Just retrieve them or search them? If searching, are you looking just at content or header info? If you can answer these then it would help inform the best answers...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Since Attachments can have a lot of different file-types, I guess searching in them is not very convenient. So it would be just retrieving them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the additional information that you've given, it seems that (a) you don't need to be able to search files, just retrieve them and (b) your DB is limited to 1GB. I would recommend that rather than storing the files in the DB at all, you simply store a 'key' to the file, which is probably just a unique filename.

In your database you can store the original user filename but write the attachment(s) to a filestore with a unique identifier (it could even be just a column ID or you could create a proper GUID.

This will keep your database small, and retrieving attachments from file will not take any longer than retrieving them from the DB.  When you write the file back out on retrieval, pass the original filename rather than your renamed and unique one.

If you are expecting a lot of files then you could shard storage across directories so that they don't get too large and eventually you could span across file systems if you needed.

If 1GB is the limit for both the DB and your storage then of course this probably doesn't help a lot.  In that case, yes you should compress the files, but as you're already aware, you may not get a very good compression ratio on files that are already in a compressed format.

One final point in favour of keeping the files outside of the database is that it could help to keep the DB lean, and therefore faster for backup/restore or migration activity.

Answer (score 0):

For me it depends a lot on the actual use of that mail:

first: how much traffic do you sincerely expect and how much storage you have? (if you have lots of space and few user why bother?)

second: much of the today's formats (jpg, odf documents, office documents, mp3) are already compressed so you won't get much juice out of it

third: compression could augment your CPU usage so you have to see what your traffic could be in peak hours to see if this will be a problem (most likely not)

last if you plan to use a server grade file system in your server some have transparent compression of data so you may want to invest time in other ways

on the other hands if you have very limited resources you might be compelled to compress al to reduce space consumption

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I might get into a storage-problem, I got only 1 GB for the DB and that seems to be not much, even for 1 user. Otherwise - as you said - most of the formats are already compressed, so I guess I save the work and try to expand the DB-space.

Comment: well 1 GB only is very little and I think you could talk to your boss or whoever is in charge and explain him that 1GB only for the whole email system is laughable (gmail actulay gives you 10 GB for free) and that you must get some more space, that said since CPU time is cheap (not for free though) you could compress and since you have little space every gain help you could also give a look to ZFS it has built in compression so you could set the db compression with very little effort